# Rewrite URL with dynamic parameter value by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have made one dynamic website application with core PHP.I want to rewrite pages with below :

1. I want rewrite http://www.example.com/ into http://www.example.com
2. I want rewrite http://www.example.com/page.php?id=4 into http://www.example.com/URLTitle1
3. I want rewrite http://www.example.com/page.php?id=5 into http://www.example.com/URLTitle2
4. I want rewrite http://www.example.com/page.php?id=6 into http://www.example.com/URLTitle4

I have tried one code as below but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^URLTitle1 $ page.php?id=4 [L,NC]
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: Is there meant to be a pattern to the 2-4 rules? It looks fairly random

Comment: No.There is customize about URLTitle  for ID.

Comment: Take a look at RewriteMap :http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html